# How to stop the normal force from being too small on a 2D rigidbody? (Java 2D)

Tags: java, 2d, physics, rectangles

I am trying to create a 2D game engine in Java with LWJGL 3. For now the objects are only rectangles with box colliders. For the collision detection I change the edge of the rectangles in to lines with the y = ax + b structure. One of the rectangles has a rigidbody component, that gives it the ability to move and interact with environment. The idea for now is to give the rigidbody a force at the start, gravity turned off, no friction, and a perfect bounce (bounciness=1). It all works very well, till it hits a rectangle with no vertical and horizontal edges. I found out that if the non-rigidbody objects are rotated by an angle other than 90 or 180 degrees the normal force is wrong (too small), how wrong depends on the rotation. The rotation of the rigidbody doesn't contribute to the problem.

```java
Vector2 rotSurface = new Vector2(-collision.surface.ToVector().y, collision.surface.ToVector().x).getNormalized();

System.out.println("Angle: "+Physics.Angle(rotSurface, rb.force));

Vector2 normalForce = rotSurface.multiplyBy(rotSurface.multiplyBy(rb.force).getMagnitude());

rb.force = rb.force.add(normalForce).multiplyBy(1f - rb.friction).add(normalForce.multiplyBy(rb.bounciness));
                           
System.out.println("Angle: "+Physics.Angle(rotSurface, rb.force));
System.out.println("===");
```

Am I doing something wrong here with calculating the new rigidbody force or the normal force itself? If you need more information to help me solve this problem please ask.

Classes that I use in the code above:

```java
public class Collision {
    Collider collider;
    ArrayList<Vector2> contactPoints = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    Vector2 center = Vector2.zero;
    Line surface;
    
    public Collision(Collider collider, ArrayList<Vector2> contactPoints, Line surface) {
        this.collider = collider;
        this.contactPoints = contactPoints;
        for(int i = 0; i < contactPoints.size(); i++) {
            center = contactPoints.get(i).add(center).divideBy(2);
        }
        this.surface = surface;
    }
}

class Line {
    Vector2 begin, eind;
    public float rc = 0;
    public float b = 0;
    public float x, y;
    public boolean vertical = false;
    public boolean horizontal = false;
    
    public Line(Vector2 begin, Vector2 eind) {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.eind = eind;
        if(begin.y == eind.y) {
            this.y = begin.y;
            this.horizontal = true;
        }
        else if(begin.x == eind.x){
            this.x = begin.x;
            this.vertical = true;
        } else {
            this.rc = (eind.y - begin.y) / (eind.x - begin.x);
            this.b = GetB(rc, begin);
        }
    }
    
    public float GetB(float rc, Vector2 punt) {
        return punt.y - (rc * punt.x);
    }
    
    public Vector2 GetIntersection(Line l2) {
        float x_ = rc - l2.rc;
        if(vertical) {
            x_ = x;
            if(l2.horizontal) {
                return new Vector2(x, l2.y);
            }
            else if(!l2.vertical){
                //System.out.println("gert");
                return new Vector2(x, l2.rc * x + l2.b);
            }
        } else if(horizontal) {
            if(l2.vertical) {
                return new Vector2(l2.x, y);
            } else if(!l2.horizontal) {
                return new Vector2((y-l2.b) / l2.rc, y);
            }
        } else {
            if(l2.vertical) {
                return new Vector2(l2.x, rc * l2.x + b);
            } else if(l2.horizontal) {
                return new Vector2((l2.y - b) / rc, l2.y);
            }
        }
        if(x_ == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        float getal = l2.b - b;
        x_ = getal / x_;
        float y_ = rc * x_ + b;
        return new Vector2(x_, y_);
    }
    
    public Vector2 ToVector() {
        return eind.substract(begin);
    }
    
    public float GetDisTo(Vector2 point) {
        Vector2 point1 = begin.add(eind).divideBy(2);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point1.x - point.x, 2) + Math.pow(point1.y - point.y, 2));
    }
    
    public boolean Overlaps(Line line) {
        if(horizontal && y == line.y) {
            if(((line.begin.x > begin.x && line.begin.x < eind.x) || (line.eind.x > begin.x && line.eind.x < eind.x)) ||
               ((begin.x > line.begin.x && begin.x < line.eind.x) || (line.eind.x > line.begin.x && eind.x < line.eind.x)))
            return true;
        } else if(vertical && x == line.x) {
            //return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Vector2 {
    float x, y;
    public static Vector2 zero = new Vector2(0, 0);
    
    public Vector2(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public Vector2 multiplyBy(Vector2 vector) {
        return new Vector2(x * vector.x, y * vector.y);
    }
    
    public Vector2 multiplyBy(float getal) {
        return new Vector2(x * getal, y * getal);
    }
    
    public Vector2 divideBy(Vector2 vector) {
        return new Vector2(x / vector.x, y / vector.y);
    }
    
    public Vector2 divideBy(float getal) {
        return new Vector2(x / getal, y / getal);
    }
    
    public Vector2 add(Vector2 vector) {
        return new Vector2(x + vector.x, y + vector.y);
    }
    
    public Vector2 substract(Vector2 vector) {
        return new Vector2(x - vector.x, y - vector.y);
    }
    
    public float getMagnitude() {
        return (float)Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    }
    
    public Vector2 getNormalized() {
        return divideBy(getMagnitude());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of a bad calculation?  What values do you expect to see instead?

Comment: I expect the angle between the normal of the surface and the force of the rigidbody to be the same before and after bounce. I have to correct myself in the beginning the normal force is bigger than it should be and later it is smaller than it should be. @markspace

Comment: @markspace With the walls rotated 20 degrees I get these results: 
Angle: 79.03625
Angle: 46.22171
===
Angle: 43.77829
Angle: 34.154377
===
Angle: 55.84562
Angle: 39.223904
===
Angle: 39.223907
Angle: 60.873882
===
Angle: 29.126114
Angle: 46.576946
===
Angle: 43.423065
Angle: 65.480736
===
Angle: 24.519272
Angle: 38.94699
===
Angle: 51.05301
Angle: 71.46484
===
Angle: 18.535156
Angle: 28.622688
===
Angle: 61.377304
Angle: 73.88454
===

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using a sinus.
I replaced

```java
Vector2 normalForce = rotSurface.multiplyBy(rotSurface.multiplyBy(rb.force).getMagnitude());
```

with

```java
Vector2 normalForce = rotSurface.multiplyBy((float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians((double) (90f - Physics.Angle(rotSurface, force)))) * force.getMagnitude());
```